# Android draws 9-path drawable at the top of canvas instead off specified position

Tags: android, canvas, view, drawable, draw

I make custom view with complex background, that consists of two elements: at the top - bitmap drawable and bellow it 9-path drawable.

My code is:

```
public class MyCustomFrame extends FrameLayout
{
    Drawable main, top;

    public RequestInfoBottomContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

         main = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_main);
         top = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_top);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();


        top.setBounds(0, 0, width, top.getIntrinsicHeight());
        main.setBounds(0, top.getIntrinsicHeight(), width, height);

        top.draw(canvas);
        main.draw(canvas);

    }
}
```

For example, if top drawable height is 10 px, width is 500 px, height 200 px and I set bounds 0, 10, 500, 200 to main drawable Android draws it 0, 0, 500, 200 bounds. I.e. main draws over top.

What I do wrong?

Comment: `top.getIntrinsicHeight()` may be returning 0. Can you check for that?

Comment: It always returns value > 0. In my case value is 10.

Answer (score 0):

I make small work around, but it is no good.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height - top.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
main.setBounds(0, 0, width, bmp.getHeight());
main.draw(new Canvas(bmp));
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, top.getIntrinsicHeight(), null);
bmp.recycle();
```